# Use Ajax to talk with PHP and get data from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

What format for the response should be?
XML or JSON??
Can it be parsed?
I have tried before using Java when developing my Android native apps
but now, I am trying to write apps using JQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

you can use json and yeah it can be parsed easily if you transfer back json

try jquery .post method for example :

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
 function(data){
   console.log(data.name); // John
   console.log(data.time); //  2pm
 }, "json }
```

Comment: thx, can you explain more about what is the meaning of "{ "func": "getNameAndTime" }"??

Comment: @red23jordan func is the post variable only, in your php file you will get it like $funcname = $_POST['func']; and you will check the value and program accordingly in php maybe call some function based on the value of $func.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a native function JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() which makes it very simple to send/receive data. PHP also has an equivalent function to format data in Javascript Object Notation

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question .....

The data can be XML / JSON / HTML / whatever format you want .... you just need to deal with that format in Javascript to present to the user.

For example if you are using an ajax based table then the output might be JSON or XML. But if you are loading in a div or a section of a page - you might return HTML that has been though a VIEW layer in an MVC based application.

There are many methods for doing this - if you give specific examples or things you have tried it would make things a lot easier ....

Comment: actually, I just want to get table in database server and display it in listview using JQueryMobile

Answer (score 1):

Both XML and JSON can be used and parsed.

I recommend JSON!

**For example:**

If you have a XML document with many levels of nested nodes you might end up with multiple nested loops ($.each function from jQuery).

The advantage of JSON is that it's very easy to get the data you need since its already native javascript. You won't need parsers or proxies, just loop the data fast and simple.

XML is more human-readable but if you document your JSON responses, you won't have any problems with future modifications.

In PHP it's very easy to generate a JSON string from an array of data brought from the MySQL DB (use `json_encode(<<insert array here>>)` function).

Have fun,

Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

JSON. use `json_encode()` to pass a php array containing your data back to the frontend.